# how can I save my work on Python 2.7.8 command line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have python 2.7.8 command Line, and every time I exit it, I lose my progress. Is there a way to save it or make files on the comand line?

Answer (score 0):

Check IPython and IPython notebook. Use IPython and save what you did to a python script file , say foo.py, by `%save` command:

```
%save 'foo' n1-n2 n3-n4 ...
```

where n1-n2, ... are line number of beginning and end to save.  To resume your work, run the file in ipython:

```
%run foo.py
```

Then, all variables in the script are accessible and you can proceed from that point.

In case of you want save your code with documentation, [IPython notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) is a perfect fit. In a web browser, you run your codes. Then, it saves history of your codes and their outputs in a session. So you can resume your work from the session. It is also very readable and you can export your work in HTML, PDF, and so on.

Comment: Thank you. Am I able to publish my games and apps that I code on Ipython notebook and IPython?

Comment: For games and apps, you'd better to ***serialize*** python objects to save, and write them into files. Pickle is widely used for the serialization.